# python - celery - modify time on scheduler

Tags: python, celery

```
time = 5

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],  # Ignore other content
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_TIMEZONE='Asia/Seoul',
    CELERY_ENABLE_UTC=False,
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
       "ADDING TASK": {
           "task": "add",
           "schedule": time,
           'args': (16, 16)
        }
    }
```

)

I tried to change time while running.
But this method doesn't work.
How can I change the time using celery scheduler while running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default beat scheduler just reads from the static setting. You can also [add entries](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries) using `add_periodic_task`.

You can also provide your own [custom scheduler](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#using-custom-scheduler-classes) class. For example, `django-celery-beat` provides a `DatabaseScheduler` that lets you read and update scheduled tasks from a database.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If possible, can you give me an example of django-celery-beat ?